# Quasitriangular Sweedler bialgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

Say we have Sweedler Hopf defined like here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweedler%27s_Hopf_algebra. We define universal R-matrix:
$$R_\lambda=\frac{1}{2}(1\otimes1+1\otimes g-g\otimes1+g\otimes g)+\frac{\lambda}{2}(x\otimes x+x\otimes gx+gx\otimes gx-gx\otimes x)$$
In order to check if it's quasitrinagular we need to verify:
\begin{equation}
(\Delta\otimes id)R=R_{13}R_{23}
\end{equation}
Left hand side can be done easily using bialgebra compatibility condition and properties of g and x:
$$\Delta(ab)=\Delta(a)\Delta(b)$$
$$\Delta(g)=g\otimes g\quad\quad \Delta{x}=1\otimes x+x\otimes g$$
It goes as follow:
\begin{eqnarray}
(\Delta\otimes id)R&=&\frac{1}{2}(1\otimes1\otimes1+1\otimes1\otimes g+g\otimes g\otimes1-g\otimes g\otimes g)\\
&+&\frac{\lambda}{2}((1\otimes x+x\otimes g)\otimes x+(1\otimes x+x\otimes g)\otimes gx\\
&+&(g\otimes g)(1\otimes x+x\otimes g)\otimes gx-(g\otimes g)(1\otimes x+x\otimes g)\otimes x)
\end{eqnarray}
But the problem is I can't decipher right hand side and do explicit check. In case of simple R like $R=a\otimes b$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
R_{23}&=&1\otimes a\otimes b\\
R_{13}&=&a\otimes 1\otimes b\\
R_{13}R_{23}&=&=a\otimes a\otimes bb
\end{eqnarray}
But how to understand it in case of multicomponent R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have maps $\phi_{ij}:A\otimes A\to A\otimes A\otimes A$ for $i<j$ and $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$. The subscript tells you where the terms of your $2$-tensor are mapped to in the $3$-tensor, in the sense that: $\phi_{12}(f\otimes g)=f\otimes g\otimes 1$. Where as you write at the end of your question:
$$R_{23}=\phi_{23}(R)$$
$$R_{13}=\phi_{13}(R)$$
$$R_{13}R_{23}=\phi_{13}(R)\phi_{23}(R)$$

Hence, for example

$$R_{13}=\frac{1}{2}(1\otimes1\otimes 1+1\otimes1\otimes g-g\otimes 1\otimes1+g\otimes 1\otimes g)+\frac{\lambda}{2}(x\otimes1\otimes x+x\otimes1\otimes gx+gx\otimes1\otimes gx-gx\otimes1\otimes x)$$
$$R_{23}=\frac{1}{2}(1\otimes1\otimes1+1\otimes1\otimes g-1\otimes g\otimes1+1\otimes g\otimes g)+\frac{\lambda}{2}(1\otimes x\otimes x+1\otimes x\otimes gx+1\otimes gx\otimes gx-1\otimes gx\otimes x)$$

Where hence
$$R_{13}R_{23}=\frac14(1\otimes1\otimes1+1\otimes 1\otimes g-g\otimes 1\otimes 1+g\otimes 1\otimes g+1\otimes 1\otimes g+1\otimes 1\otimes g^2-1\otimes g\otimes g +1\otimes g\otimes g^2-g\otimes 1\otimes 1-g\otimes1\otimes g+g\otimes g\otimes 1-g\otimes g\otimes g+g\otimes 1\otimes g+g\otimes 1\otimes g^2-g\otimes 1\otimes g^2+g\otimes g\otimes g^2)+\cdots$$
where I've only bothered to multiply the first term of each, and haven't reduced the terms by the relations.

Comment: Ok, but how to understand $R_{13}(R)R_{13}(R)$? How to multiply sums of 3-component tensors?

Comment: @kishony See edit. You're just multiplying in the standard way for a tensor algebra. $$(\sum_i (b_i\otimes c_i))(\sum_j(b_j'\otimes c_j'))=\sum_{ij}(b_ib_j'\otimes c_ic_j')$$

Comment: you wrote $R_{12}(R)$ where you meant $\phi_{12}(R)$, and so on.

Comment: That's a lot of work to do. Thank you very much!

Comment: @kishony, you should probably review what  the tensor product is, how linear maps are defined on them, and what the tensor product of algebras is before continuing to read about quasi-triangular Hopf algebras and what not: you will avoid lots of pain... You seem to not be familiar with the very basic stuff and it is really unlikely that the theory of Hopf algebras will ever make sense in that situation!